# Flat base semi-circular arch-like image with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the series of concentric shapes, this is another drawing that I'm unable to figure out. The top is not quite a complete semi-circle. Note that some of my labels got left out in the scan.

[image]

Comment: Are there any  constant elements in the shape? The number of subdivisions of the arc is always the same or is it variables? Same question for the subdivisions in the base.

Comment: base usually is divided in two halves. it is the concentric dome that is divided into 2, 3 or 4 equal portions. Same holds for another post following this one.

Comment: where is  the center?

Answer (score 3):

You can try some thing like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=.2cm,inner sep=0pt,scale=1.5,line width=.7pt,line join=round]
\draw (180:3)coordinate[label=left:a](a) arc (180:30:3) coordinate[label=right:f](b)--(30:2.5)coordinate[label=left:6](c) arc (30:170:2.5)coordinate[label=above right:1](d)--cycle;
\draw (a)--(1.6,0)coordinate[label=right:g](g)|-coordinate[label=above:7](e) (d);
\draw (c)--(e) (b)--(g);
\foreach \ang/\num/\lett in {150/2/b,120/3/c,90/4/d,60/5/e}{
\draw (\ang:2.5)--(\ang:3) node at (\ang:2.3) {\num};
\node at (\ang:3.2) {\lett};
}
\coordinate[label=below:h] (o) at (0,0);
\draw (o)--(d-|o)node[above]{8};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```