# semi-circular arch with rect base

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to adapt the solution provided to my earlier question [Flat base semi-circular arch-like image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270463/flat-base-semi-circular-arch-like-image-with-tikz) to make the arc an exact semi-circle.

This is the best I got so far. How to close the inner arc symmetric on right as in left (lot of clutter on right half), instead of joining to f. The base should be rectangular, the top side extending to outer arch How to eliminate the 1-a line? Assistance/suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=.2cm,inner sep=0pt,scale=1.5,line width=.7pt,line join=round]
\draw (180:3)coordinate[label=left:a](a) arc (180:0:3) coordinate[label=right:f](b)--(30:2.5)coordinate[label=left:](c) arc (30:170:2.5)coordinate[label=above right:1](d)--cycle;
\draw (a)--(2.6,0)coordinate[label=right:g](g)|-coordinate[label=above:7](e) (d);
\draw (c)--(e) (b)--(g);
\foreach \ang/\num/\lett in {150/2/b,120/3/c,90/4/d,60/5/e,30/6/k}{
\draw (\ang:2.5)--(\ang:3) node at (\ang:2.3) {\num};
\node at (\ang:3.2) {\lett};
}
\coordinate[label=below:h] (o) at (0,0);
\draw (o)--(d-|o)node[above]{8};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=.2cm,inner sep=0pt,scale=1.5,line width=.7pt,line join=round]
\draw (180:3)coordinate[label=left:a](a) arc (180:0:3) coordinate[label=right:g](b)--(10:2.5)coordinate[label=above left:7](c) arc (10:170:2.5)coordinate[label=above right:1](d)--cycle;
\draw (a)--(3,0)--(c)--(d);
\foreach \ang/\num/\lett in {150/2/b,120/3/c,90/4/d,60/5/e,30/6/f}{
\draw (\ang:2.5)--(\ang:3) node at (\ang:2.3) {\num};
\node at (\ang:3.2) {\lett};
}
\coordinate[label=below:h] (o) at (0,0);
\draw (o)--(d-|o)node[above]{8};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

With the base semi-rectangular:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=.2cm,inner sep=0pt,scale=1.5,line width=.7pt,line join=round]
\begin{scope}
\path[draw,clip] (180:3)coordinate(a) arc (180:0:3) coordinate[label=right:g](g)--cycle;
\draw(10:2.5)coordinate[label=above left:7](c) arc (10:170:2.5)coordinate[label=above right:1](d);
\draw[shorten >=-2cm, shorten <=-2cm](c)--(d);
\end{scope}

\foreach \ang/\num/\lett in {150/2/b,120/3/c,90/4/d,60/5/e,30/6/f}{
\draw (\ang:2.5)--(\ang:3) node at (\ang:2.3) {\num};
\node at (\ang:3.2) {\lett};
}
\coordinate[label=below:h] (o) at (0,0) node[left]at(a){a} node[right]at(g){g};
\draw (o)--(d-|o)node[above]{8};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helps. For the base, I was trying to manipulate your code so as to have a clean rectangular shape that touches the outer circle. How  to extend 1-7 outwards? The numbers 1 and 7  can stay where they are.

Comment: @jayr -- Do you mean a perfect rectangle with all sides as straight line segments or the rectangle can have its right and left sides as part of the outer semi-circle?

Comment: Yes. It is more rectangular (right/left sides slightly curved to match the semi-circle's curves) that has it right/left sides aligned with semi circle. What's the segment that connects 1-a, 7-g (those 45 deg lines)?

Comment: @jayr -- Please see my update.